# How to implement language Translation in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to implement language translation in my app. Could anybody tell how to do that. Actually i am not able to find APIs for it and google translation API v2 is paid.

Comment: You should seriously consider using a paid-for translation service to get the best results, especially if you intend for your app to go on the Appstore and even more so if you want to charge for it.

Comment: You say "Could anybody tell how to do that" Do you mean the translation of the phrases? Or the integration of translated phrases?
I'll delete my answer if you already know how to accomplish localization

Answer (score 4):

To localize strings in your code:

-Create a new Localization.strings file

> File -> New File -> iOS -> Resources -> Strings file

-Select this file and Show the file inspector

> <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

-Click the add button under localization and add a default language (I expect English) and the other languages you want.

-You'll notice that you have a little arrow next to your `Localizable.strings` file, if you click it, you can see the languages that you've added.

-For each phrase you want to translate, use the following syntax:

```
"key" = "value"; 

"hello" = "bonjour";
```

-In your code where you want to use the translation, use `NSLocalizedString(@"hello", @"hello");` (The second parameter is a comment, it doesn't matter what value you use here)

When it comes to nibs, you'll need to manually change the strings and re-arrange the text fields etc in each nib.

Comment: I think that Varun was asking about *translation*, not *localization*.

Comment: Yeah p4010!! I want to do language translation for entered text in English to another language. I found its solution...Thanks!!

Comment: If you have solution then please post it as an answer. This way other developers with same question can have that solution too :)

Comment: @varun Mehta---- please share if you have solution for this.......i also need it!  Thanks in advance!